# bootstrap перекрывает стили css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Доброго времени суток друзья. В проекте имплементированная библиотека стилей Bootstrap перекрывает стили css прописанные в ручную. Проверил на наличие порядка стилей(не стоит ли boostrap выше заданных мною стилей в строке), всё в порядке. Но на сайте введенные изменения не отображаются. Всё стоит по дефолту как было задано ранее. что делать?

Comment: `!important` добавить, видимо. откройте в браузере панель разработчика да посмотрите.

Comment: @teran .brd8{
  background-color: #e1e4e8;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid rgb(181, 176, 185);
  margin: 20px !important;
  width: auto;
  padding: 20px !important;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;

}

Comment: всё равно не пашет

Comment: проверяйте уровень вложенности,
возможно стили boostrap по уровню выше чем ваши.
а вообще смотрите в инспекторе,
там будет наглядно видно что и где и чем у нас затирается.

Comment: @Yamich teran заработало всем спасибо. В разных папках находились файлы css с идентичными именами и из за этого возникал конфлик. Бог знает как при таком конфликте стили умудрялись работать